# Row Reduction of matrix with distinct complex powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to reduce the following matrix given distinct complex numbers $\beta_1,
\beta_2,...,\beta_N$ with the knowledge that $N \geq M+1$.

From my testing I can see that this reduces to an identity matrix with $N=M+1$, and if $N > M +1$ any rows after row $M+1$ become all zeroes.

But I'm unsure of how to fully show this in a convincing argument.

$\begin{bmatrix} (\beta_1)^M& (\beta_1)^{M-1}& ... & \beta_1 & 1\\
(\beta_2)^M & (\beta_2)^{M-1} & ...  & \beta_2 & 1
\\ \vdots &\vdots & &\vdots & 1 
\\ (\beta_N)^M & (\beta_N)^{M-1} & ... & \beta_N & 1
\
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first the case where $N = M + 1$, and let $A$ be the given matrix. Further, let $B_N$ be the matrix with $1$s in the off-diagonal, and $0$s elsewhere, e.g.
$$B_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Then
$$AB_N =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \beta_1 & \cdots & \beta_1^M \\
1 & \beta_2 & \cdots & \beta_2^M \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & \beta_N & \cdots & \beta_N^M
\end{bmatrix}$$
is a [Vandermonde Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), and is invertible if and only if $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots, \beta_N$ are all distinct. Since $B_N$ is its own inverse, it follows that $A$ is also invertible. Hence, row reduction will yield the identity matrix, as conjectured.

Now, if $N \ge M + 1$, then we can simply ignore rows $M+2, M+3, \ldots, N$, and row reduce the first $M + 1$ rows. By the above argument, they will also reduce down to the identity matrix. Now that a pivot exists in each column, one can easily reduce the rows below to $0$ rows.

So, in conclusion, all your conjectures are true.